# MapView and setRegion:animated: YES not animating

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I using MapView and setRegion:animated:YES, but the map is not animating?

It was working fine before and not just stopped all of sudden. Now the map just draws at the location I am trying to animate to?

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Where do you call the setRegion:animated method, e.g. viewDidLoad?

Comment: No view a button that is a subview of the mapview (its like Google maps take to the user location pin button). The little arrow icon button.

Comment: If I drag the map past 20 miles from its last point I call a special method that does a webservice call and it shows a HUD. If drag the map under 20 miles and push the home button it animates. But if I drag past 20 miles and the webserver call goes out and the HUD is shown, when the HUD goes away and I push the home button it won't animate. Is there any MKMapMethod that once called prevents the map from animating anymore?